# Angular - reload page when tab is selected?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, browser, reload

Is there a way to trigger a function to reload the page when the user clicks the browser tab of my Angular app?

I believe this would be done with window.location.reload(), but I'm not sure how to make this line be triggered on tab selection.

I'm thinking this could be done by making the body/html have a "onfocus='reloadPage()'" attribute, but I don't want it to refresh 500 times as I'm moving my mouse around the page, just once when the tab is focused/clicked.

Comment: With Angular, you might want to not try reloading the page. Any specific reason behind it ?

Comment: Yes - our application uses JBOSS/Wildfly to host our Angular app to a webpage. JBOSS/Wildfly is a Windows Service (also works with linux). The service must be on/running for you to login to our webapp. So, when Wildfly is not running, I have code to show a message "Wildfly is down or needs to be restarted". But I've noticed that once I do start Wildfly back up, the error message doesn't go away until I manually refresh the page. I don't want it randomly checking every couple minutes, I just want it to reload the page when the user clicks the tab so they don't think it's still down/not running.

Comment: Cool. My suggestion would be without reloading, you could implement a timeout call back function, where it checks the status again and could make the message appear away.

Answer (score 6):

I like @enjoibp3 solution, but instead of adding event listeners and removing them. You're better off using `@HostListener` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener))

```js
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:focus') onFocus() {
    console.log('window focus');

    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

See stackblitz code sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvs7gr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and demo project [here](https://angular-ivy-rvs7gr.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Because it's Angular, I would drop that into my app.component.ts file under `ngOnInit`

### Update

Per the comments below you should also remove the event listener on destroy as well.

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        window.addEventListener('focus', this.reloadPage);
    }

    reloadPage(): void {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        window.removeEventListener('focus', this.reloadPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to remove the event listener by declaring this function *outside* of ngOnInit: 

reloadPage = function(e) {
  window.location.reload()
}

Then, I added this in my ngOnInit() in the same file: 

window.addEventListener('focus',this.reloadPage)


Then, TO REMOVE THE EVENT LISTENER, I put this in my ngOnDestroy() in the same file:

window.removeEventListener('focus',this.reloadPage)

Comment: @CollinFox good call, I probably should have added that as well!

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the event listener as all event listeners are destroyed when you reload a page.

Comment: my application goes from the login page to the home page so if I don't remove the event listener it would continue to keep checking for the condition every time I click / focus on the window even on the home page where it's not needed

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with javascript, paste this to your chrome console, and change tabs see how it works

```
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { 
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (!document[hidden]) {
        var initialPage = window.location.pathname;
        window.location.replace(initialPage);
    }
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
```